# WordPress front end pages are not working after moving to the hosting server

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I am a new WordPress. My WordPress project is working well on local, but when I upload to the hosting server, the wp-admin page is working but the front end is not.

I did the following:

1. In hosting MySQL database, I changed local site url to the current domain site url.
2. changed http to https

Can anyone help me fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Moving a Wordpress site can be tricky if you're new to Wordpress. There are a *lot* of things that can go wrong and it can take hours to fix.

I suggest using [a plugin such as Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to move a WP website in just a few minutes - it is very simple to use:

1. Install it on your local WP **site to copy** and build a package (just a couple of clicks).
2. Copy this ZIP file and installer to the **new location** and run the installer wizard.
3. Create an **empty database**
4. Run the **installer wizard** which has just a few (very) short steps to go through - you just need to have your database details.

You can have an entire site set up & running perfectly on a new location in just minutes! No more setting up the database, changing urls in the database, 404 errors, broken links, broken images, etc. Moving a Wordpress site manually can be tricky and you can waste hours trying to fix the issues. Even agencies use a plugin to avoid the problems.