# Migrating Wordpress with divi or elementor

Tags: json, wordpress, elementor

I use this commands to migrate in the old day, but with divi or elementor, some crash with migration, anyone use other way ? other idea ? It's due to Json ?

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-site.com', 'https://www.new-site.com')
WHERE option_name = 'home'
OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.old-site.com', 'https://www.new-site');

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'https://www.old-site.com', 'https://www.new-site.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://www.old-site.com','https://www.new-site.com');
```

Thanks

Comment: For migrating Wordpress sites in future, I recommend using a plugin designed to do it. See this answer about [migrating a WP site to a new location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321555/wordpress-front-end-pages-are-not-working-after-moving-to-the-hosting-server/62323847#62323847) I avoid using plugins and am very familiar with WP, SQL etc, but this is one thing I always use a plugin for - its can save you so much time and has never failed on me yet after years of using it :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the guid as that will cause RSS readers to think that all of the posts are now new unread posts.

You might be missing some stuff to replace. Typically when migrating to the new site you do the find and replace on everything in the database (except for the guid). There are some tools that can help you out with this. If you use wp-cli, you can use the `wp search-replace` command. Otherwise, [this is a great tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). Both of these tools will automatically handle doing a proper search and replace inside of any serialized strings.

Also remember to clear out your cache.