# problem on moving Wordpress website from Localhost to Server

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, filezilla, ovh

I ve created my wordpress website on local, then I hosted it using ovh and filezilla

I followed these steps

1. upload source files under www fileZilla
2. import my database on ovh
3. update wp-config

The problem is when i launch my site it still get css files from localhost nd showing this error
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: It’s very tricky to migrate a WP website manually. I suggest using a plugin such as Duplicator that does all the hard work for you and you can have a fully working site up and running in just a few minutes. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321555/wordpress-front-end-pages-are-not-working-after-moving-to-the-hosting-server/62323847#62323847) for what to do

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import a WordPress database and have it just work because there are plenty of hard links (including hostname, in your case `localhost`) in it.

There are several ways to change the URL in the database. My favorite way is to use `wp-cli` ( https://wp-cli.org/ ) on the command line. Once installed and having the `wp` command inside your PATH, you can change (cd) to your WP installation's root directory (where the `wp-config.php` file is located) and run the following command:

```
wp search-replace 'http://localhost' 'https://your-new-domain.com' --export=my_wp_export.sql
```

Replace your-new-domain.com by whatever you're using on your ovh host. Be careful when selecting `http` or `https` depending on whether you have a valid SSL certificate in place and your hosting is correctly set up for HTTPS, or not.

You now have an SQL file where each localhost URL is replaced by your-new-domain.com. Next, upload and import the `my_wp_export.sql` file - everything should work.